# How to make angularjs typing a global in my project

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I'm working on a project that has pulled in Typescript definitions the deprecated [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) way and I would like to now move over to using the @types method instead.

Currently we have a typings.json file in the root of the project like so:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20161101124950",
    "angular-cookies": "registry:dt/angular-cookies#1.4.0+20160317120654",
    "angular-material": "registry:dt/angular-material#1.1.0-rc5.0+20161208205836",
    "angular-resource": "registry:dt/angular-resource#1.5.0+20160914132003",
    "angular-translate": "registry:dt/angular-translate#2.4.0+20160729132354",
    "d3": "registry:dt/d3#0.0.0+20160907005744",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160929162922",
    "lodash": "registry:dt/lodash#4.14.0+20161110215204",
    "moment": "registry:dt/moment#2.11.1+20161010105546",
    "require": "registry:dt/require#2.1.20+20160919185614"
  },
  "resolution": "src/client/typings",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-local-storage": "registry:dt/angular-local-storage#0.1.5+20160726182927",
    "angular-ui-router": "registry:dt/angular-ui-router#1.1.5+20161222093745",
    "requirejs": "registry:npm/requirejs#2.2.0+20160319062357"
  }
}
```

As you can clearly see, these are currently installed as globals and are appearing in a `src/client/typings` folder in our dir structure.

I can already see I have a @types folder under my node_modules which contains some of the typings I have listed in this typings.json file.

In our tsconfig.json file we have an includes config section:

```
"include": [
        "./typings/index.d.ts",
        "./app/**/*.module.ts",
        "./app/**/*.run.ts",
         "./app/**/*.routes.ts",
        "./app/**/*.enum.ts",
        "./app/**/*.controller.ts",
        "./app/**/*.model.ts",
        "./app/**/*.directive.ts",
        "./app/**/*.filter.ts",
        "./app/**/*.service.ts",
        "./app/interfaces/**/*.ts"
    ],
```

I have since commented out the `./typings/index.d.ts` to be sure none of the older typings (not in the @types folders) are being pulled in.

Now, when I look at an .ts file for some angularjs code, I see the angular object is not being resolved anymore:

[image]

Having read around, I can just add an import to the file to resolve this (e.g. `import * as angular from 'angular'`), but it would mean I would need to add to every one of our .ts files that contain any angular code.

Is there an easy\recommended way I can make the angular reference a global in my project, or is best practice to add these fine grained imports across all the files where needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a common .ts file under 'Typings' folder and add all required reference in that file like below.

[image]

After that, only add common .ts file reference to all the place where ever all reference required like below.

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/common.d.ts" />
```